# How to get actual number dynamically changed by CSV using Javascript or Java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, csv

When user exporting CSV data in my spreadsheet program, large numbers are converted into scientific or exponential numbers in the cells.

After importing the CSV file from the user, I am getting converted an exponential number in my javascript code.

For example, when customer import the CSV file, and a customer's phone number is listed as 8008286650; upon opening up the file in Excel, they are seeing the number shown as 8.01E+09 or something similar.

I read many articles and I know that there isn’t an easy way to control the formatting Excel applies when opening a .csv file, and I can't force the user to add apostrophe or space in the cell with the actual value.

Can I get the plain number in my code (8008286650) at the time of reading of the cell values in the place of "8.01E+09" using some javascript code?

Regards

Comment: If you check the CSV file in a text editor you will see the correct values for those figures. The issue you describe is purely due to the way Excel formats large numbers by default. There's also nothing you can do about it, as you cannot apply cell formatting to a CSV file. All you can do is educate your users.

Comment: Excel by default for CSV does some default conversions based on some assumptions which are incorrect.  If you rename the file to .TXT when importing into Excel, then Excel will display the Text Import Wizard which allows specifying the data formats.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/861964/how-do-i-stop-excel-from-converting-value-0503e000-to-5-03e02-automatically/862073 refer this

Comment: No, You cannot get the plain number because if the number is converted to scientific notation because the precision is lost when Excel does the conversion.

Comment: if there is no way to converting back in actual number then it seems I have to stop using CSV file because I can't educate my user. Earlier they are using microsoft excel 97-2003 worksheet (.xls) for the data import process. so Is there any way so that I can generate a microsoft excel 97-2003 worksheet (.xls) file using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, I have solved the same issue using this.

```
decimal[] numbers = {43564765876978, 56576867897699, 45765879789789};

string path = @"D:\text.csv";

string[] lines = numbers.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);

lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
//result:
//43564765876978 
//56576867897699 
//45765879789789
```

Comment: Akshay, are you getting number like 8.01E+09 when you import the spreadsheet and changing back to 43564765876978 in code using your javascript code?

Comment: I am getting `4.35648E+13` in excel sheet and  getting `43564765876978` in javascript code.

Comment: Akshay, for example I am getting aaray in this form when I import the spreadsheet ------ > "O", "4.76112E+15", "", "", "V", "", "", "102", "15", "", "840", "", "", "8024851159", "", "12/1/2018", "QVI020", "1", "", "", "90" . 4.76112E+15 is the formatted card number. now I am getting the value in my jvascript code. then to format what I have to write so that I can get 43564765876978 value. your code is a C#  code or javascript code ?

Comment: It is a __c#__ code and above code worked for me to get desire value in file.

Comment: Akshay, I need the same functionality but using javascript.